# Generated ng-table sort is not working

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I would like to display something like this:

[image]

And by clicking on a column header(th), sort my table.
But, I don't manage to use the ng-table component with my data structure. The table displays correctly but sort is not working.

[**Not working demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HBvjDzxCfHIHla5J8isx?p=preview)

HTML

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
    <tr class="keyword-info">
        <th></th>
        <th ng-repeat="keyword in AppKeywords[0].keywordDensity">{{keyword.keyword}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="keyword-info" ng-repeat="app in AppKeywords">
        <td><span class="bold">{{app.name}}</span><br>{{app.totalKeywordDensity}}% ({{app.totalKeywordCount}})</td>
        <td sortable="'stats.density'" ng-repeat="stats in app.keywordDensity">{{stats.density}}% ({{stats.number}})</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10          // count per page
}, {
    total: $scope.AppKeywords.length, // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {

        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
            $filter('orderBy')($scope.AppKeywords, params.orderBy()) :
            $scope.AppKeywords;

        $scope.AppKeywords = $filter('orderBy')($scope.AppKeywords, params.orderBy());
        $defer.resolve($scope.AppKeywords);
    }
});
```

AppKeywords:

[image: Console.log($scope.AppKeyword)]

Comment: This is pretty tricky how about  JSFiddle chum?

Comment: I did a Plunker, I put the link in my initial question.

Comment: Just had a look, it's not clear that anything that should be working isn't. Could you update to clearly indicate what the desired functionality is?

Comment: http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/3 -- I want the same functionality on my table. For example, when I click on music, I would like to the table rows be sorted by asc or desc music density (the %).

Comment: Could you write that into the fiddle?

Comment: It's done, in the description.

Comment: Had a look and though you are close, the code is much too complicated to be able to troubleshoot. You'll want to put an orderBy filter on your `<tr>` and add a custom filter though. That's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your table is structured but Usually ng-table sortable requires '',

so try with

```
<td sortable="'stats.density'" ng-repeat="stats in app.keywordDensity">{{stats.density}}% ({{stats.number}})</td>
```

Comment: The way you are using ng-table is wrong, infact you are not using ng-table at all. You are just contructing the table with normal ng-repeat, here sorting has to be handled on your own.

Comment: You need to repeat your rows using the ng-table syntax like below

Comment: <th ng-repeat="keyword in $data"> where all your sorting will be done by ng table using the $data